# Counting particular occurrences in python in csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with 4 columns {Tag, User, Quality, Cluster_id}. Using python I would like to do the following: For every cluster_id (from 1 to 500), I want to see for each user, the number of good and bad tags(Obtained from the quality column). There are more than 6000 users. I can read only row by row in the csv file. Hence, I am not sure how this can be done.

For example:

```
Columns of csv = [Tag User Quality Cluster]   
Row1= [bag  u1  good     1]  
Row2 = [ground u2 bad   2]  
Row3 = [xxx  u1 bad  1]  
Row4 = [bbb  u2 good 3]
```

I have just managed to get each row of the csv file.

I can only access each row at a time, not have two for loops. The psedudocode of the algorithm I want to implement is:

```
for cluster in clusters:  
    for user in users:  
        if eval == good:  
            good_num = good_num +1  
        else:  
            bad_num = bad_num + 1
```

Comment: Some demo data would be helpful.

Comment: Questions here should be asked after some effort on your part, what have you tried?

Comment: I have edited my question and hopefully made it more clear

Comment: I am not familiar with formating in stackoverflow, but I have tried my best to explain the problem.

Comment: I fixed the formatting in your Python code.

Comment: Thank you so much for formatting the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since someone's already posted a `defaultdict` solution, I'm going to give a [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) one, just for variety.  `pandas` is a very handy library for data processing.  Among other nice features, it can handle this counting problem in one line, depending on what kind of output is required.  Really:

```
df = pd.read_csv("cluster.csv")
counted = df.groupby(["Cluster_id", "User", "Quality"]).size()
df.to_csv("counted.csv")
```

--

Just to give a trailer for what `pandas` makes easy, we can load the file -- the main data storage object in `pandas` is called a "DataFrame":

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv("cluster.csv")
>>> df
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 500000 entries, 0 to 499999
Data columns:
Tag           500000  non-null values
User          500000  non-null values
Quality       500000  non-null values
Cluster_id    500000  non-null values
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
```

We can check that the first few rows look okay:

```
>>> df[:5]
   Tag  User Quality  Cluster_id
0  bbb  u001     bad          39
1  bbb  u002     bad          36
2  bag  u003    good          11
3  bag  u004    good           9
4  bag  u005     bad          26
```

and then we can group by Cluster_id and User, and do work on each group:

```
>>> for name, group in df.groupby(["Cluster_id", "User"]):
...     print 'group name:', name
...     print 'group rows:'
...     print group
...     print 'counts of Quality values:'
...     print group["Quality"].value_counts()
...     raw_input()
...     
group name: (1, 'u003')
group rows:
        Tag  User Quality  Cluster_id
372002  xxx  u003     bad           1
counts of Quality values:
bad    1

group name: (1, 'u004')
group rows:
           Tag  User Quality  Cluster_id
126003  ground  u004     bad           1
348003  ground  u004    good           1
counts of Quality values:
good    1
bad     1

group name: (1, 'u005')
group rows:
           Tag  User Quality  Cluster_id
42004   ground  u005     bad           1
258004  ground  u005     bad           1
390004  ground  u005     bad           1
counts of Quality values:
bad    3
[etc.]
```

If you're going to be doing a lot of processing of `csv` files, it's definitely worth having a look at.

Comment: I have problems reading the csv file. The column Tags contain user entered tags, so it has characters like "", ; 17th century, spaces, # which are mistakenly entered by the users. When I try to open csv file, it shows error: CParserError: Error tokenizing data.

Comment: Hi. Using this method, is there a way to write the results into a csv file. I tried the following. I tried to print the values of the different quality metrics in a row using `values = group["quality"].value_counts() ` and printing values to csv file, but I only obtain the values. Is there a way where I can get the column names as different types of quality eg: usefulness-useful, not-useful, problematic etc and their respective counts in csv file. @DSM

Answer (score 3):

`collections.defaultdict` should be a great help here:

```
# WARNING: Untested
from collections import defaultdict

auto_vivificator = lambda: defaultdict(auto_vivificator)

data = auto_vivificator()

# open your csv file

for tag, user, quality, cluster in csv_file:
    user = data[cluster].setdefault(user, defaultdict(int))
    if is_good(quality):
        user["good"] += 1
    else:
        user["bad"] += 1

for cluster, users in enumerate(data):
    print "Cluster:", cluster
    for user, quality_metrics in enumerate(users):
       print "User:", user
       print quality_metrics
       print  # A blank line
```

Comment: I am trying out both methods using pandas and collections.defaultdict, but with this method I get error:

user = data.[cluster].setdefault(user,defaultdict(int))
                ^SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @user1992696 - apologies, there was an errant period in `data[cluster]`.

Comment: It seems to work, but I get this as the output:  
`Cluster: 490 User: 0 4 User: 1 8`
But I want the user with user_id as in user column along with the positive and negative values for each user. Something like  
user: user_001    
positive: 23  
negative:4
How can I modify the code to obtain such result?