# Separate out value_counts values

Tags: python, csv, pandas

So I originally had referenced [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540504/counting-particular-occurences-in-python-in-csv-file) to get me started.

I was able to change the code to get the data I need, but now I'm trying to get JUST the data values. At the end of the day, I'm going to be doing a lot of value counting for each column (count instances of unique values). First are the csv headers and second is the code I currently have.

```
tripduration    starttime   stoptime    start station id    start station name  start station latitude  start station longitude end station id  end station name    end station latitude    end station longitude   bikeid  usertype    birth year  gender

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("January2015BikeData.csv")
ok=[]
for name,group in df.groupby(["start station id"]):
    ok.append(group["start station id"].value_counts(sort=True))

print(ok)
```

That code outputs something like:

```
Name: start station id, dtype: int64, 79    566
Name: start station id, dtype: int64, 82    310
Name: start station id, dtype: int64, 83    258
```

With the first number being the ID and the second being the COUNT. Is there a way to get JUST the numbers(id and count)? This is mainly so I can export this data to another function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
count = df.loc[:, 'start station id'].value_counts()
tuples = [tuple((x, y)) for x, y in count.items()]
```

Comment: Looks like that did it! Is there a way to turn the result into a well-formed tuple?

(x,y),(x,y) ...etc?

Comment: Gotcha, just use a generator to create the tuple object. Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Try zipping the index and the values:

```
gb = df.groupby('start station id')['start station id'].count()

pairs = zip(gb.index, gb.values)
>>> pairs
[(79, 566), (82, 310), (83, 258)]

>>> ['x: {0}, y: {1}'.format(x, y) for x, y in pairs]
['x: 79, y: 566', 'x: 82, y: 310', 'x: 83, y: 258']
```

Comment: And then I could just iterate over that object using a regular for x in y: format correct?