# Counting grouped string occurrences in csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I just started python because of exactly this problem. I read the old thread from [Counting particular occurrences in python in csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540504/counting-particular-occurences-in-python-in-csv-file) but I cannot get my counting to work.

My csv file looks like this:

```
course     year of birth   sex
300        1998            w
300        1998            m
500        1995            w
```

What I need is to count for every course the number of males and females per year of birth.

I tested importing the first 15 rows of the csv file with

```
print df[:15]
```

which worked fine.
But the counting does not work. I think it is because of the format of the column sex. It ist string, because of f and m for indicating male and female course attendees.

At the end I want a csv file like this:

```
course     date of birth    sex    sum per sex  
300        1981             m      5  
300        1981             f      3  
300        1982             m      1  
300        1982             f      4
```

I tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("myFile.csv")

for name, group in df.groupby(["course", "dateOfBirth"]):
    print 'group name:', name
    print 'group rows:'
    print group
    print 'sum per sex:'
    print group["sex"].value_counts()
    raw_input()
```

I played with changing the grouping, but until now I do not quite get how it works. Maybe the bread I want to eat is too big for an absolute beginner ;o)

### Edit 1

I read some documentation and got my code to work -- at least it is countung the genders per year and course.

Because I could not quite get the answer from Neo-X (thanks a lot for your time to answer me!) to work I had to work on mine:

```
# Result should be a csc file like this:
#
# course year    gender   sum
# 200    1930    m        2
# 200    1930    w        1
# ...
# 300    1989    m        2
# 300    1989    f        2
# 300    1990    m        3
# 300    1990    f        2
#

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("course_year_gender.csv")

# check the first 15 rows if data looks okay:
print "--------------------------------------------------------"
print "Show the first 10 rows to check if file is ok"
print "--------------------------------------------------------"
print df[:15]
print "--------------------------------------------------------"

# empty line
print '\n'
# then we can group by gender and year and do work on each group:
print "--------------------------------------------------------"
print "Grouped data"
print "--------------------------------------------------------"
for name, group in df.groupby(["course", "year"]):
    print "----------------------------"
    print 'group name:', name
    #print 'group rows:'
    #print group
    print 'Total per gender:'
    print group["gender"].value_counts()
```

It returns this:

```
...
group name: (300, 2010)
Total per gender:
f    2
m    2
Name: gender, dtype: int64
----------------------------
group name: (300, 2011)
Total per gender:
m    3
f    1
Name: gender, dtype: int64
----------------------------
group name: (300, 2012)
Total per gender:
m    7
f    5
Name: gender, dtype: int64
...
```

Any suggestions how I can get the output as a csv like table? Something like this

```
print group["course", "year", "gender"].value_counts()
```

did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You codes work, what you need to do is to create a new dataframe to store the result from the `for` loop of grouped data.
See [Intro to Data Structures](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html).

To make things easier, you may want to use the following method to replace your `for` loop, then store the returned `series` data to the new dataframe.

```
df.groupby(['course', 'year', 'sex']).size()
```

data

```
course,     year,            sex
300,        1998,            f
300,        1998,            f
300,        1998,            m
300,        1995,            m
500,        1995,            f
500,        1998,            m
```

gives

```
course  year  sex          
300     1995              m    1
        1998              f    2
                          m    1
500     1995              f    1
        1998              m    1
```

see [Group By: split-apply-combine](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer my question! I experimented with your proposal but did not get to far.

I changed my code to this: